# Streaming audio from PC to Android using GStreamer

Tags: android, gstreamer, audio-streaming

Here's the pipelines

//Linux PC

```
gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw-int, rate="(int)44100", channels="(int)1", endianness="(int)1234", width="(int)16" ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux max-delay=50 max-page-delay=50 ! tcpserversink host=192.168.0.101 port=36631
```

//Android

```
gst-launch-0.10 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.0.101 port=36631 ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, rate="(int)44100", channels="(int)1", endianness="(int)1234", width="(int)16" ! autoaudiosink
```

And I get the following error message. Could not link audioconvert0 to autoaudiosink0. This pipelines works on PC, and I tried different caps but no success, also test autoaudiosrc with autoaudiosink on Android and it also works.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, remove quotation symbols

gst-launch-0.10 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.0.101 port=36631 ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=44100, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16 ! autoaudiosink